# Conditional sum in Python based on row input

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do a conditional sum-product in Python. The simplified idea is as follows:

```
A = [1 1 2 3 3 3]
B = [0.50 0.25 0.99 0.80 0.70 0.20]
```

I would like to have as output

```
Total1 = 0.50*1 + 0.25*1
Total2 = 0.99*2
Total3 = 0.80*3 + 0.70*3 + 0.20*3
```

I was thinking to use a FOR ... IF... structure, to specify that for a given value in `A` all corresponding values in `B` should be summed.

In reality it's a huge dataset, so I will have to make the script capable to loop through all categories?

At this moment I'm struggling to get the idea translated to an appropriate Python script.
Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you clarify the relationship between A and B?

Comment: Sure, some context:

I have an excel file of company names (rows), with in **columns** 
1° 'type' = A 
2° percentage to be applied = B 

I need to get the sum of percentages for each type of company. 

Hope this helps! If not, shoot!

Comment: What's the product in this case? Seems like you just want a sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like an excellent fit for [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (assuming the values in `A` are **sorted**, it probably wouldn't work correctly for `A=[1,1,2,2,1]`):

```
from itertools import groupby
A = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
B = [0.50, 0.25, 0.99, 0.80, 0.70, 0.20]

for key, grp in groupby(zip(A, B), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    grp = [i[1] for i in grp]
    print(key, key * sum(grp))
```

which prints:

```
1 0.75
2 1.98
3 5.1
```

You could also store it in a list instead of printing the values:

```
res = []
for key, grp in groupby(zip(A, B), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    grp = [i[1] for i in grp]
    res.append(key*sum(grp))
print(res)
# [0.75, 1.98, 5.1]
```

---

In case a 3rd party package might be an option for you, you could also use [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import groupedby
>>> from operator import itemgetter, add

>>> {key: key*sum(value) for key, value in groupedby(zip(A, B), key=itemgetter(0), keep=itemgetter(1)).items()}
{1: 0.75, 2: 1.98, 3: 5.1}
```

or using the `reduce` parameter of `groupedby` directly:

```
>>> groupedby(zip(A, B), key=itemgetter(0), keep=lambda x: x[0]*x[1], reduce=add)
{1: 0.75, 2: 1.98, 3: 5.1}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [`iteration_utilities`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package.

Comment: Thanks for the great responses!! :) 

One more question, the values in A are not sorted.. Could be for example:
A = [1 1 1 2 3 2 1 4 2 1]

the values in B are matching to these in A in these order. So if I sort A, B is not matching anymore?

Comment: In that case you can `sort` the `zip`. Instead of using just `zip(A, B)` you have to use `sorted(zip(A, B), key=lambda x: x[0])` (sorting based on A without loosing the corresponding value from B). That only applies to `itertools.groupby` though - for `iteration_utilities.groupedby` it doesn't need to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! :)

Is there an option to do this for 10 different B colums? Or is it better to just run the program 10 times?

Comment: That depends on how the different `B` columns are stored. Normally you could just put that in a loop `for B in all_different_B_columns:`. However you could just ask *another question* about it and include how the `B`s are stored (in what container). :) It's a bit too hard to answer this in the comments.

Comment: Okay, thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635983/itertools-groupby-looping-over-different-columns

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with something like this. There is edge case I have no idea what to do with and which hopefully could be removed:

```
In [1]: sums = {}
In [2]: A = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
   ...: B = [0.50, 0.25, 0.99, 0.80, 0.70, 0.20]
In [3]: for count, item in zip(A, B):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         sums[count] += item * count
    ...:     except KeyError:
    ...:         sums[count] = item * count
    ...:         

In [4]: sums
Out[5]: {1: 0.75, 2: 1.98, 3: 5.1}
```

Edit:

As suggested in comments `deafultdict` could be used to get rid of this ugly `try-except` block:

```
In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: sum = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

In [4]: sum[1]
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: sum
Out[5]: defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>, {1: 0})
```

EDIT2:

Well, I've learned something today. After more comments:

```
In [6]: sums = defaultdict(int)

In [7]: A = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
   ...: B = [0.50, 0.25, 0.99, 0.80, 0.70, 0.20]

In [8]: for count, item in zip(A, B):
   ...:     sums[count] += count * item
   ...:     

In [9]: sums
Out[9]: defaultdict(int, {1: 0.75, 2: 1.98, 3: 5.1})
```

Comment: you can use a `defaultdict` initialized at 0 to avoid the `try - except` block

Comment: Instead of using `lambda:0` just use `int`. That works because `int()` (without argument) returns `0` :)

Comment: Thanks, it looks pleasant now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

results = [group * sum(v[1] for v in values)
           for group, values in itertools.groupby(zip(A, B), itemgetter(0))]
```

This assumes that all the equal numbers in `A` are adjacent to one another. If they might not be, you'd either need to sort them or use a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using numpy for this and assuming that the groups are ordered, you can do it by:

```
A = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
B = [0.50, 0.25, 0.99, 0.80, 0.70, 0.20]
A = np.asarray([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
B = np.asarray([0.50, 0.25, 0.99, 0.80, 0.70, 0.20])
index = np.full(len(A),True)
index[:-1] = A[1:] != A[:-1]
prods = A*B

#result
res = np.add.reduceat(prods, np.append([0], (np.where(index)[0]+1)[:-1]))
```

Additionally, given you have large lists, this could really speed up operations

Comment: Just for completeness: The approach mentioned in this answer is *partially* based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634302).