# Take sum of numpy array based on a boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `prods` and`index`

```
prods = np.asarray([ 0.5 ,  0.25,  1.98,  2.4 ,  2.1 ,  0.6 ])
index = np.asarray([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I need to calculate the sum of the values in `prods` array using the `index` array. The output I want to is

```
res = [0.75, 1.98, 5.1]
```

The first `True` in `index` array is preceded by a `False`, so I take the first two elements from `prods`(.5,.25) and sum them up(0.75). The second `True` in index has no preceding `False` (since its preceded by a `True`, the `False` at position zero doesn't count), so I simply output 1.98 in this case. The third `True` is preceded by two `False`, so I take those values from `prods` array (2.4,2.1,0.6) and sum them up. Any ideas on how to do this?

I basically need something like `np.cumsum` but I need to return the cumulative sum every time a `True` occurs in index and reset the cumulative sum value to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) and using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) of your `index` array as positions to split:

```
>>> [arr.sum() for arr in np.split(prods, np.where(index)[0]+1)[:-1]]
[0.75, 1.98, 5.0999999999999996]
```

The last one isn't exactly `5.1` because of floating point precision. If you don't want to use `Fraction`s or `Decimal`s there's nothing you can do about that.

---

You could also use [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) here:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(prods, np.append([0], (np.where(index)[0]+1)[:-1]))
array([ 0.75,  1.98,  5.1 ])
```